# Adding a new variable to an existing class/constructor

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm doing a project for university (Java, not advanced!) , we have a miniature railway, and we are doing the software part for it.

I have a technical question.

All the classe, methods, ecc are already done, all we need to do is to create an extension.

Mine is a GUI which allows you to remove or add trains from the railway.

For example, for adding a train I have a combo box with the possibile parameters, and a "ADD TRAIN" button, the code behind is :

```
private void addTrainActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        //creates a new train with given parameters, it adds it to the railway

        Train t = new Train(id, locomotive);

        railway.getTrains().add(t);
```

what I still miss, is the code for the "REMOVE A TRAIN" part!

There is a combo box which display the existing train, you choose one, then there is a DELETE TRAIN button, and it should remove the train from the railway,

for now the code is simply this:

```
private void removeTrainActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


        railway.getTrains().remove(selectedTrain);
```

but there is an issue. 
There are some OBSERVERS, that whatch the railway searching for events (like a train stopped, or not in right route) which are triggered if the event occurs.

The professor said that the Remove Train code I wrote, doesn't work because we need to kill all the related observers for the train we want to remove!

He said:

What I suggest is to have a "isDeleted" variable in the train.
When you delete the train, remove it from the railway, and set the
variable to 1. For example, in the "OnRouteSecured Observer", in the process, if
isDeleted==true, do nothing (return).

So that's what I need to add, but the issue is that I don't really know how to add a new variable to the train!!

For creating a train I just use the constructor already there, I don't know If I must add this variable to the Train Class or where!

If you need some more infos I will provide!

Hope you can help, thank you!

Comment: Have you ever programmed before? (no offense)

Comment: The teacher is wrong. First of all, using 1 instead of true is a bad advice. Second, removing the observers from the removed train doesn't serve any purpose. The train, since removed, won't fire eny event anymore. It will even be garbage collected if it's not reachable anymore. There would be a problem is the removed train was registered as an observer of other objects, but that is not what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what your teacher is suggesting is merely adding a Class variable to your object.

```
public class Train {

    private boolean deleted = false;

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return this.deleted;
    }
}
```

In the future I would start by talking to your TAs or professors before posting on StackOverflow as you go to a university for a reason.

Comment: thank you very much for your input!
Usually I always ask the TAs for help, but it's the weekend and they don't answer, and I need to finish this part asap, so I asked here!

Can I ask you to explain me the code you wrote? because If I put the code directly in netbeans, in the Train class, it gives error saying that '' ; '' is expected (I put ; after return this.deleted instead of the dot, but doesn't change!  I didnt understend the public boolean isDeleted {... part! thank you

Comment: I edited the code to make it correct. isDeleted() is a method allowing to know whether the train is deleted or not.

Comment: thank you very much, now it's much more clearer, I have still a question, in the GUI source code, when I write the code for the DELETE TRAIN button, I put:

railway.getTrains().remove(selectedTrain);

and then how can I write in java:

"take the train variable DELETED, and set it on TRUE", 

the variable DELETED is in the class Train as you told me!

then the last thing to do, I suppose is to go in the observer, and add the rule: if Deleted = true, don't trigger any event for this train! thank you again

Comment: I think I made it, I created a SETTER in the train class:

public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
          this.deleted = deleted;
          }
and in the GUI under the REMOVE TRAIN button, I have this code:

 railway.getTrainById(selectTrain.getSelectedItem().toString()).setDeleted(true);

 railway.getTrains().remove(selectedTrain);

have I done it right? thank you